# Form Input previous values suggestions not shown correctly CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

The previous input suggestions element is getting affected by the CSS styles.
Somehow it is misbehaving when I get into responsive view in the inspect element window.

[image]

[image]

**But when I resize the whole browser then it works fine -**

[image]

Html for the input element-

```html
<div
            className='ModalWrapper Modal__Fullscreen '
            showModal={showModal}
          >
            <CloseModalButton
              className='CloseModalButton'
              aria-label='Close modal'
              onClick={() => setShowModal((prev) => !prev)}
            />
            <div className='ModalSection1'>
              <div className='modal__content1'>
                <p className='modal__welcome'>Welcome Back</p>
                <p className='modal__signin'>Sign in to continue.</p>
              </div>
              <div className='ModalBottomImg'>
                <img className='big' src={bottomImg} />
                <img
                  className='mobile'
                  src={topImg}
                  style={{ width: '100%' }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='ModalSection2'>
              <div className='modal__content2'>
                <div className='google__login'>
                  <img
                    src='data:image/png;base64,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'
                    alt='gl'
                  ></img>
                  <p>Continue with Google</p>
                </div>
                <div className='modal__seperator'>
                  <hr></hr>
                  <p>or</p>
                  <hr></hr>
                </div>
                <div className='home_modal'>
                  <form className='modal__form'>
                    <label>Your Full Name</label>
                    <input
                      placeholder='Enter Your Full Name'
                      type='text'
                      name='fullName'
                      onFocusOut={handleRequire}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    ></input>
                    {errors.fullName.length > 0 && (
                      <p className='modal__errors'>
                        <svg
                          className='MuiSvgIcon-root'
                          focusable='false'
                          viewBox='0 0 24 24'
                          aria-hidden='true'
                        >
                          <path d='M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-2h2v2zm0-4h-2V7h2v6z'></path>
                        </svg>{' '}
                        {errors.fullName}
                      </p>
                    )}

                    <label>Your Email Address</label>
                    <input
                      placeholder='Enter Email Address'
                      type='text'
                      name='email'
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    ></input>
                    {errors.email.length > 0 && (
                      <p class='modal__errors'>
                        <svg
                          class='MuiSvgIcon-root'
                          focusable='false'
                          viewBox='0 0 24 24'
                          aria-hidden='true'
                        >
                          <path d='M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-2h2v2zm0-4h-2V7h2v6z'></path>
                        </svg>{' '}
                        {errors.email}
                      </p>
                    )}
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input
                      placeholder='Enter Password'
                      type='password'
                      name='password'
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    ></input>

                    {/* <svg
                      class='MuiSvgIcon-root visiblity'
                      focusable='false'
                      viewBox='0 0 24 24'
                      aria-hidden='true'
                    >
                      <path d='M12 7c2.76 0 5 2.24 5 5 0 .65-.13 1.26-.36 1.83l2.92 2.92c1.51-1.26 2.7-2.89 3.43-4.75-1.73-4.39-6-7.5-11-7.5-1.4 0-2.74.25-3.98.7l2.16 2.16C10.74 7.13 11.35 7 12 7zM2 4.27l2.28 2.28.46.46C3.08 8.3 1.78 10.02 1 12c1.73 4.39 6 7.5 11 7.5 1.55 0 3.03-.3 4.38-.84l.42.42L19.73 22 21 20.73 3.27 3 2 4.27zM7.53 9.8l1.55 1.55c-.05.21-.08.43-.08.65 0 1.66 1.34 3 3 3 .22 0 .44-.03.65-.08l1.55 1.55c-.67.33-1.41.53-2.2.53-2.76 0-5-2.24-5-5 0-.79.2-1.53.53-2.2zm4.31-.78l3.15 3.15.02-.16c0-1.66-1.34-3-3-3l-.17.01z'></path>
                    </svg> */}

                    {errors.password.length > 0 && (
                      <p class='modal__errors password_error'>
                        <svg
                          class='MuiSvgIcon-root'
                          focusable='false'
                          viewBox='0 0 24 24'
                          aria-hidden='true'
                        >
                          <path d='M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-2h2v2zm0-4h-2V7h2v6z'></path>
                        </svg>{' '}
                        {errors.password}
                      </p>
                    )}

                    <button class='home__login' type='submit' disabled>
                      Next
                    </button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='modal__contentbottom'>
                <hr></hr>
                <p>
                  By signing up, you're agreeing to our{' '}
                  <span>Terms of Use</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                  Already have an account? <span>Log In</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS for the Form container, two columns

```css
form {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0em;
}
.modal__form > label {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #201e27;
  margin: 0.625rem 0 2%;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.6;
  max-width: 42em;
}
.modal__form > input {
  border-radius: 0.3125rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.6rem;
  width: 96%;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-family: Inter;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  caret-color: #48ccac;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.modal__form > input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #48ccac;
}
.modal__errors {
  color: #e0133e;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.01em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.modal__errors > .MuiSvgIcon-root {
  color: #e0133e !important;
  font-size: 1.1rem !important;
}
.MuiSvgIcon-root {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  user-select: none;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.visiblity {
  position: relative;
  top: -2.6rem;
  right: -22rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Media queries for the mobile adjusting the two columns

```css
@media (max-width: 770px) {
  .ModalSection2 {
    height: fit-content;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 415px) {
  .ModalWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .CloseModalButton {
    position: fixed !important;
    color: grey;
  }
  .ModalSection1,
  .ModalSection2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .modal__content2 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 27.2px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  
  
}
@media (max-width: 415px) {
  .ModalSection2 {
    min-height: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: unset;
  }
  .ModalSection1 {
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

What is going on here? What is that element called and how to manipulate it ?

Comment: The CSS by itself  is useless for us if we don't know structure of your HTML.

Comment: @vanowm added !

Comment: Can you post generated html, not a template, so we can see it first hand.